# Click anywhere to send request in Angular

Tags: angularjs

I just started to work with Angular, and it's pretty good to implement.

Does Angular have a function like jQuery to `click` anywhere or on `HTML` to perform some task?

Like jQuery has

```
$("html").click(function() {});
```

Is it possible in Angular?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, yeah, of course. I don't know why you would though. Just use ng-click in your view

```
<body ng-app="rootApp" ng-controller="RootController" ng-click="hello()">
</body>
```

and define the hello function in your controller.

```
var rootApp = angular.module('rootApp');

rootApp.controller('RootController', ['$scope',
function ($scope) {
    $scope.hello = function() {
        alert('hello');
    }
}]);
```

Also note that you will need to expand the height of your page in css if you want the whole page to be clickable

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could attach an ngClick directive to the body tag:

```
<body ng-app="app" ng-click="doSomething()" ng-controller="ctrl">
...
</body>
```

JS

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.controller('ctrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.doSomething = function() {
        alert('done');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be accomplished by adding an ng-controller to your html element and an ng-click that calls a method in your controller.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="hello" ng-click="check()">

  <head>
    <script data-require="angular.js@*" data-semver="1.3.7" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.7/angular.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <h1>Hello Plunker!</h1>
    <script>
      var myApp=angular.module("myApp",[]);
      myApp.controller("hello",function($scope){
        $scope.check=function(){
          alert("hello");
        }
      });

    </script>
  </body>

</html>
```

See this plnkr for a demo:
http://plnkr.co/edit/KVUz6dNcXKj3W9uTNYLa?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

You need to create controller and inside controller you need create one function on controller.

```
<button ng-click="ShowMessage()">Show Message</button >

var app = angular.module('app', []); app.controller('Myctrl',
function($scope) {
$scope.ShowMessage = function() {
alert('Test');
}); });
```